# Determine the smallest sigma-algebra A on $\Omega$

Tags: measure-theory

We consider the sample space $\Omega =\mathbb{N}$. Determine the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak A$ on $\Omega$ to which applies: $\\$
If $n \in\mathbb{N}$ is an even number, then $\left\{{n}\right\} \in \mathfrak A.$

I don't quite know. Can anybody please help?

---

So far I have come to the following:

First, we claim that any subset $A \subseteq \mathbb N$ containing only even numbers must be in $\mathfrak A$. If A is finite, $A=\left\{{a_1,..., a_n}\right\}$, then we set

$$A_i = \left\{a_i\right\} \text{  for  } i =1,...n$$

According to the precondition $A_i \in \mathfrak A$, so according to the third axiom for $\sigma$-algebras also applies

$$ {\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\in \mathfrak A}. $$

If A is infinite, but A is in any case still countable (since whole $\mathbb N$ is countable), we can write $A=\left\{{a_1,..., a_n,...}\right\}$. Let's put

$$A_i = \left\{a_i\right\} \text{    for   }  i \in N $$

$A \in \mathfrak A$ are after precondition, so after the third axiom for sigma-algebras also applies here

$$ {\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in \mathfrak A}. $$

Thus necessarily all subsets of $\mathbb N$, which contain only even numbers, must be in $\mathfrak A$.

---

I don't know how to go on from here.

Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. What's $\Omega$? The way you wrote it initially, $\Omega $ is a natural number. But then you want $\mathcal A$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, which makes me think that $\Omega$ is some subset of $\mathbb N$. Then you say $n\in\mathcal A$ which makes no sense (the elements of a $\sigma$-algebra are subsets), so maybe you meant $\{n\}\in\mathcal A$. But then it's hard to know what you asking, since if $\Omega$ was arbitrary?

Comment: My Bad, you're absolutely right about your assumptions, I corrected the question, now it should be right. Ω is the sample space, it is the set of all possible outcomes or results of (say) an experiment. I meant {n} ∈ A and not n ∈A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is right. Let $E,O\subset\mathbb N$ be the subsets of even and odd nubmers respectively. You showed that $E$ and all its subsets are in $\mathfrak A$. Since $\mathfrak A$ needs to have complements, you also have $O\in\mathfrak A$. And then 
$$
\mathfrak A=\{\varnothing, \mathbb N, O, E, \text{subsets of $E$}, \text{ sets } O\cup B\ \text{ where }B\subset E\}.
$$
This is closed under taking complements and unions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but why should one deal with intersections to determine the smallest sigma-algebra?

I thought it's all about that:

A subset $\mathfrak A \subseteq \mathfrak P(\Omega)$ is called $\sigma$-algebra, if it holds:

$1. \mathfrak A \neq \emptyset$

$2.\,  A \in \mathfrak A \Rightarrow  \overline A \in \mathfrak A$

$3.\, A_n \in \mathfrak A \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb N \Rightarrow {\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n\in \mathfrak A}. $

Could you explain this to me, please?

Comment: Is it about being able to prove either this(union) or that (Intersection)?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I'm still not sure, why you wrote "$\text{sets } O\cup B\ \text{ where }B\subset E$". 
Is it necessary to write that?

Comment: How would you write it?

Comment: As I wrote in the following anwer, but I don't know, if that's right.

Answer (score 0):

**The following answer is a summary of the answers from @Martin Argerami and me.**

---

Let $E \subset \mathbb N$ be the subset of even nubmers and $O \subset \mathbb N$ be the subset of odd nubmers.
So for $n\in \mathbb N$ let's define then $E_n=\{n\ \mathrm{even}  \,|\,  n\in \mathbb N\}$ and $O_n=\{n\ \mathrm {odd}  \,|\,  n\in \mathbb N\}$

The union of these $E_n$ and $O_n$ over all subsets of $\mathbb N$ does actually give all the subsets of even and odd numbers.

We claim now that $ E$ must be in $\mathfrak A$. According to the precondition $E_n \in \mathfrak A$.
The only condition that could possibly cause difficulties here is the third. Here we distinguish two cases:

$1. \,$ If $E$ is finite:

according to the third axiom for $\sigma$-algebras, it must apply here:
$$E_n=\{n\ \mathrm{even}  \,|\,  n\in \mathbb N\} \Rightarrow  E= {\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} E_n\in \mathfrak A}. $$
Note that: $E=\left\{{e_1,..., e_n}\right\}$

$2.\,$ If $E$ is infinite:

Let's put

$$E_i=\{i\ \mathrm{even}  \,|\,  i\in \mathbb N\} \Rightarrow E = {\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\in \mathfrak A}. $$
Note that: $E=\left\{{e_1,..., e_n,...}\right\}$

Thus necessarily $E$ and $E_n$ must be in $\mathfrak A$.

Since $\mathfrak A$ needs to have complements, we also have $O\in\mathfrak A$. And then 
$$
\mathfrak A=\{\varnothing, \mathbb N, O, E,E \cup O\}.
$$

"This is closed under taking complements and unions".

Comment: @Martin Argerami, is this right?

Comment: No. Your $\mathfrak A$ does not have the set $\{2\}$. Nor any other even number or combination thereof, for that matter, which was precisely the requirement.

Comment: How to solve that?

Comment: As in my answer. $\ $

Comment: I failed to understand your entire answer:
may you explain, why you wrote only "subsets of E" and not "subsets of O" and why
$\text{ sets } O\cup B\ \text{ where }B\subset E$?

Comment: " Subsets of $E$"  was a requirement of your question. Subsets of $O$ are not needed; if you include them, your $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.